# Generating C code for functions of different signatures, but same implementation

Tags: c, templates

A situation I run into a lot in writing C code (context is scientific computation) is that I will have functions which have exactly the same body modulo minor type differences. I realize C++ offers the template feature and function overloading which allows one to have only one copy of said function and let the compiler figure out what signature you meant to use when you build.

While this is a great feature in C++, my project is in C and I furthermore do not need the full power of templating. So far what I have tried is m4 macros on a candidate source file, and this spits out respective .c files with appropriate name mangling for the different types I need. The preprocessor could therefore accomplish this as well, but I'm attempting to avoid using it in complicated ways (my code needs to be understandable for reproducibility reasons). I'm not very good with m4, so all the files have been hacks that only work in specific cases and are inapplicable in new situations.

What do other people programming in C do when this is necessary? Manually produce and maintain the different permutations of function signatures? I'm hoping that isn't the best answer, or that a tool exists to automate this dreary and error prone task.

Apologies for vagueness, let me give a toy example. Suppose I have need to add two numbers. The function might look something like this:

```
float add(float x,float y){
   return x+y;
}
```

Ok that's great for floats, but what if I need it for a wide range of types on which arithmetic is available. Ok I can do this

```
float add_f(float x,float y){...}
double add_lf(double x,double y){...}
unsigned int add_ui(unsigned int x, unsigned int y){...}
```

and so forth. If for some (probably stupid) reason I decide I need to also write the contents of the arguments to a binary file, I now have to add in the requisite file I/O code in every single function. Is there a simple way/tool to take an add function and spit out different ones with name mangling to avoid this annoying situation?

Basically in my m4 cases I would just find/replace a macro TYPE with the requisite type, and have a macro MANGLE() which mangles the functions, then I point the output to an alternate .c file. My m4 skills are lacking though.

Function pointers can help with the ultimate interface of my code, but eventually those pointers have to point to something, and then we're just enumerating all the possibilities again. I'm also unclear on how this might affect potential inlining of short functions.

Comment: Awfully vague and imprecise.  Can you provide a [**SSCCE**](http://sscce.org/)??

Comment: Complicated macros are you're only real good solution in C for template like behavior. Otherwise in general, if you really want C++ specific features you need to write C++ code

Comment: M4 is a good preprocessor, and you may try to learn more of it. But for more complex code-generated situations it is usually better to write a template file and write a script that does the substitutions as the project needs them.

Comment: @Pyrce The thing is I'm not looking for actual template like behavior. I don't mind carrying over name mangling schemes myself and having the compiler be completely ignorant of them. I just want a way to avoid having to maintain 10+ different functions whenever something unrelated to types change. This isn't something I have to do often either, so switching to C++ for seems overkill.

Comment: what types are you trying to generalize? What kind of calculations are you required to do in your algorithm?

Comment: @eyalm Floats and ints usually. Sometimes calculations can range through needing float,double,float _Complex, double _Complex, int, unsigned int, unsigned long, etc. The work is primarily matrix arithmetic or some kind of stencil loop, but the various types and precisions can change depending on the context, and this can happen within the same code as well so typedefs don't quite cut it.

Comment: While I think your question is well-written, I agree with @abelenky that it would help to see a working example of what you're trying.

Comment: also, though dirty you could do something like `void my_generic_func(void * data, unsigned flags);` and interpret the `void *` as per the type given in `flags`

Answer (score 3):

The only thing i can think of is: make the algorithm itself independent of the type, have the user of your function create his own function to handle the type-specific parts, and make one of the parameters to *your* function a pointer to the "handler function".

See the definition/implementation of the qsort routine for what i mean. Qsort works for all kinds of data, but handles the data itself transparently - the only things you pass to qsort is the size of each entry, and a function pointer to a function that does the real comparison.

Comment: +1, but it *will* make the OP's code more complicated to read and maintain, which he is trying to avoid.  However, this is probably the best approach to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be asking for generic type support. While the macro processing can work in restricted domains, what you are doing is complex.

If the variants are so similar that simply type and name mangling is enough, then could you not use regular C #defines before each of multiple inclusions of the same source fragment to allow the preprocessor perform the substitution? This way, at least there is only a single environment to manage.

Alternately, if the performance hit is not substantial, could you prepare multiple stub functions for each specialisation and map these to a generic version that can be called from the stubs?

Comment: I have actually done this before, using the preprocessor and multiple inclusions. It's effectively equivalent to the m4 solution I have, which I now favor because it spits out readable .c files which are then compiled. Someone reading the code wouldn't have to know what my macros mean, they could just open up one of the generated files instead and ignore the template files.

Comment: @Reid.Atcheson Is the performance hit of always using the highest precision (perhaps keeping one integer and float version) so large that it is worthwhile maintaining the multiple implementations? The function pointers will definitely not inline, but may not be very expensive. They will result in the same kind of distributed complexity that you currently are trying to avoid.

Comment: As a general rule I keep function pointers for functions which remain outside of inner loops. My coding requirements are a little different from others though since this is research, and I'm basically just future proofing myself from someone's complaint that I pre-emptively disabled a compiler optimization by having bad coding style, and thus artificially making my implementation of someone else's algorithm slower than my algorithm (and thus need to code again..) Now if people were more attentive to reproducibility in my field and released their code, I would write interfaces like crazy.

Comment: @Reid.Atcheson If you would like to try the preprocessor again, you can provide the processed output as the resulting source. This will be plain C and should not present maintenance problems. If the data structures are bigger (like BLAS) you can obviously ignore and defer the types to the library routines and call these through macro substitutions or even tables of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I use [GNU autogen](https://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/) for code generation tasks, which sounds somewhat like your current m4 solution, but might be better organized.  For example:

**type.def**

```
autogen definitions type;

type = { name="int"; mangle="i"; };
type = { name="double"; mangle="lf"; };
type = { name="float"; mangle="f"; };
type = { name="unsigned int"; mangle="ui"; };
```

**type.tpl**

```
[+ autogen5 template 
c=%s.c
(setenv "SHELL" "/bin/sh") +]/*
[+ (dne "* " "* ") +]
*/
[+
 FOR type "\n" +][+name+] add_[+mangle+]([+name+] x, [+name+] y) { ... }[+ENDFOR+]
```

or something like that.  This should spit out a function for each of the types in `type.def` looking something like:

```
unsigned int add_ui(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) { ... }
```

You can also have it insert type-specific code in certain places if needed, etc.  You could have it output the add functions described above as well as the I/O versions.  You'd have to compute the text for `mangle` instead of what I've got, but that's not a problem.  You'd also have some conditional code for the I/O and a way to toggle the condition on and off (again, not a problem).

I'd *definitely* try and see if there was some way to generalize the algorithm, but this approach might have drawbacks (e.g. performance issues from not having the real underlying type) as well.  But it sounds from the comments that this approach might not work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I know that most C developers are afraid of it, but have you thought about using macros?

specific to your example:

```
// floatstuff.h
float add_f(float x,float y);
double add_lf(double x,double y);
unsigned int add_ui(unsigned int x, unsigned int y);
```

combined with:

```
// floatstuff.c
#define MY_CODE \
  return x + y

float
add (float x, float y)
{
  MY_CODE;
}

double
add_lf (double x, double y)
{
  MY_CODE;
}

unsigned int
add_ui (unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
  MY_CODE;
}
```

If the code you are using per function is truly identical, then this might be the solution you are looking for. It avoids most of the code duplication, maintains some degree of readability and has no impact on your runtime.
Also, if you keep the macro local to your .c file, you are unlikely to break anything, so no worries there either.

Also, you can do even more weird stuff using parameterized macros, which can give you even more reduced code duplication.

Comment: You need something more like `#define ADD(type, suffix) type add_ ## suffix(type x, type y) { return x + y; }`, which can be instantiated with `#define ADD(unsigned int, ui)` and `#define ADD(double, db)` and `#define ADD(float, fl)`, etc.